# How to access other node when all values reading on cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm a newbie at Google Cloud Functions. I am making simply  a reminder. I want to get the user's token the time came for notifying them. (for only one person) It has access to all missions in my real-time database. I found the correct time. But there is a problem with getting tokens. When I access to user's token,
My console returns me: "Exception from a finished function: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokens')".
How can I fix it?

Here is my real-time database structure:

[image]

Also here is my code:

```
exports.scheduleremindernotifications  = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}/name').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {


const usersRef = admin.database().ref('users');
usersRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const userId = childSnapshot.key;
    const consumingRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/missions`);
    consumingRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
const missions_keys = childSnapshot.key;

// Start at time elde ettik.
const startatref = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/missions/${missions_keys}/startat`);




// get to startat values (times)
startatref.once('value').then(allToken => {
if(allToken.val()){

  // use it on value for split it.
const setted_times = allToken.val();

// I must get token that user's mission has came. Also, this token must belong to the user.

const tokenim = allToken.val.tokens;



console.log(`token? ${tokenim}`);

const a = setted_times.split(" ")


// Outputs:  5 5 2023 6 8 13 UTC+3 , 6 5 2023 6 8 13 UTC+3

// I should split it all according to (" ") space such as:
//  first[0]
// second[1]
// third[2]


// Ay gun yil
const date23 = new Date(a[0] + '/' + a[1]+ '/' + a[2]).setHours(17,30,0);
const date24 = new Date('5/15/2023').setHours(17,30,0);

/* const difftime = Math.abs(date23 - date24);
const diffDays = Math.ceil(difftime / (1000*60*60*24));
console.log(diffDays + " days");
 */

if(date24 > date23)
{
  const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Test.',
        body: 'Tap here to check it out!'
    
       }}

  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenim, payload)
  console.log('Successfully sent message:');

}else if(date24 < date23 ){
  const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Test.',
        body: 'Tap here to check it out!'
    
       }}


  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenim, payload)
  console.log('Successfully sent message:');
}



}

});

});
    

} );


});
});
```